# How to return html string with react component's function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react class component  with these functions. Inside the componentDidUpdate, I would call generateHtml to get the html, and in the html, it will call bind a function called radioHandler. However, it showed an error that it could not find the function radioHandler when I click the radio button.

```
componentDidUpdate(){
    document.getElementById('spouseInfo').innerHTML = this.generateHtml()
}

generateHtml = () =>{
   return `<input name="${ele.$id.split("/")[3]}" onClick="${this.radioHandler}" type="radio" value="false"checked>` 
}

radioHandler = (event) => {
    // do something when click radio button
};
```

Comment: you shouldn't be rendering HTML strings in React, use the framework and JSX instead. As well as being much cleaner this would avoid a problem like the one you're having!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But do you know how to dynamically add my html to the render function ?

Comment: well, you'd add the HTML minus the `onClick`, and use `addEventListener` to add `this.radioHandler` as the handler. But seriously, as I suggested in my first comment, don't do this, do it the React way. Else you might as well not use React and save your users having to download the library.